# Using byte pointer for write a response using JNA

Tags: java, c, arrays, jna

I'm trying to use a function in C using JNA:

C:

```
int addHoliday(unsigned char* data);
```

JAVA:

```
int addHoliday(byte[] data);
```

I'm passing my byte[] with information, but in C I'm using the same pointer to write a response. Can I catch the same byte[] with the new information?

Comment: I think you'd want just `byte* data`, especially not unsigned...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, primitive arrays work just like memory buffers when used in a direct function call.  The native code will see a consistent buffer for the duration of the native call, and your Java code will see in the `byte[]` whatever data was written by the native code.

As for the signedness of the data, any `unsigned char` elements with the high bit set will appear as negative values in the `byte[]` in Java.  To properly extract the data, you'll need to mask out the higher bits, e.g.

```
int unsigned_value = (int)byte_value & 0xFF;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just take it as a byte pointer array:

```
int addHoliday(byte* data);
```